# For Data Transfer, REST API vs SFTP, which is more secure?

Tags: rest, security, sftp, file-transfer

Two different applications needs a data transfer from one another for certain activities. Option to do this data transfer is either prepare a file of data and push it through SFTP at certain point of time, or push/pull the changes through REST API in real time.

Which approach will be more secure if the data in one system is completely encrypted and in one it is raw?

Comment: I would like to be able to answer, but there is way too little information. Both the ssh and https protocols are - as far as I know - secure, however, there are always implementation details that make or break security.

Answer (score 3):

When choosing an integration pattern, as always, the answer is: "It depends".

1. How much data, and how frequently?
2. What is the security classification for the data (and the potential impact of a data breach)?
3. How mature are the IT Engineering/Operations/DevOps teams that will be involved in implementing the integration points, on both ends?
4. What facilities are available for ensuring that data is encrypted at-rest, as well as in-transit?
5. What is the business requirement regarding data latency?
6. What is the physical distance between the two systems?
7. What is the sustainable network connection speed between the two systems?
8. What are the hours during which the integration needs to be active/scheduled?
9. Is the data of a bulk/reference type - or is it an event/transaction nature type?
10. What is the size per message/transaction?
11. What is the total size of the data (MB? GB? PB? ...?) that needs to be transferred during a given processing cycle (per hour? per day?)?

Additional considerations that should be examined:

1. Network timeout/retry scenarios
2. Batch reruns
3. CPU, Memory, Network bandwidth utilization
4. Peak hour processing vs. off peak hour processing
5. Infrastructure/environmental limits/constraints - and cost factors (e.g. Cloud hosting limits on transactions, data, file size, Cloud-hosted API Gateway pricing strategies, ...)
6. Network Latency introduced by number of messages that must be sent to complete transfer of all data via an API vs. SFTP
7. Data Latency introduced by SFTP batch scheduling

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to compare SSH (SFTP) with SSL (RESTful API using HTTPS) as both have different functions.

SFTP has a broader surface area for attack as it uses SSH for tunneling which means there are multiple areas for there to be compromises. That does not mean it is less secure.